# Socket Error 1411

Tags: c, winsock

I am using some third party library for sending SMS via EMI protocol. It's written in C and  using winsock library. The initialization function is returning this error (Socket error 1411). The function is returning the error on this line:

```
sock = tcp_init( hostname, port);
if( sock == SOCKET_ERROR) return -1;
```

I did not find what this error means. Since some of these errors maight be OS specific, my operating system is Windows7 x64.

Comment: Can you specify which Compiler are you using? VC 8? VC 10? etc

Comment: I am using DevC++ default compiler, version 4.9.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can see [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN. It says

```
ERROR_CLASS_DOES_NOT_EXIST
1411 (0x583)    
Class does not exist.
```

Anyway, what you need is WSAGetLastError() or just [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able find this out yourself by calling [WSAGetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For all kinds of Windows Socket related calls WSAGetLastError will give you the exact error number which should be able to guide you into deciphering the problem.